# How can I get selected time and add class via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

My HTML is dynamic and like that:

```
<div class="date">
            <strong>21</strong>
            <span class="month">Jan</span>
            <strong class="year">15</strong>
            <span class="details"></span>
</div>
```

And I want get this time and print console via jQuery:

```
var selectedDate = $('.date');
console.log(selectedDate);
```

But result is not correct. How can I fix it?

EDIT:
Ok, I solve my problem with that:

```
console.log(selectedDate.text());
```

Now, I want add class if event is a past event.

```
 if (selectedDate < now) {
        $('.event').addClass('past');
      }
```

But not any error or result.

Comment: `console.log(selectedDate.text());` ?

Comment: What do you mean by time?...you're showing dates. And what does the 21 mean?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/g3xn4hfa/?

Comment: did you define `now` as a variable? what's its value?

Comment: If you have an additional different question - make a new question. Your second question is not related to your first question. You should google how to compare dates in JavaScript.

Comment: for your edit : can you change something serverside ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
selectedDate = $(".date > .month").text() + " " 
             + $(".date > strong:nth-child(1)").text() +
        " 20"+ $(".date > .year").text(); 

console.log(selectedDate); // Jan 21 2015
```

You could, of course, re-arrange those to output the date according to the format you want -