# If date greater than now add class via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

HTML:

```
<div class="date">
    <strong>21</strong>
    <span class="month">Jan</span>
    <strong class="year">15</strong>
    <span class="details"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var selectedDate = $('.events-list .date').text();
var now = new Date();
if (selectedDate < now) {
    $('.event').addClass('past');
}
```

But not add class to `event`. Whats my problem?

Comment: The text returned from the jQuery selector will be `21 Jan 15`. This is not a valid format that can be converted to a `Date()` - which you'll need to do to compare dates. You will need to amend the date to get it in to one of these formats: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please give me a sample? My HTML is dynamic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get selected time and add class via jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986289/how-can-i-get-selected-time-and-add-class-via-jquery)

Comment: plus in your code you have selectedDate less than now...

Comment: @barisxtonate - what Rory is saying is that `.text()` returns a string, so you are comparing a string (`selectedDate`) to a Date object (`now`).  Additionally, the string value of `selectedDate` (which would be "21 Jan 15") is not a valid string format for creating a Date, so, if you tried to create a Date object with it (i.e., `new Date(selectedDate)`, the result would be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert the strings individually into a format that javascript can parse to create a date object from it. Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/uew2j1pu/1/

```
<div class="date">
<strong class="day">5</strong>
<span class="month">Jan</span>
<strong class="year">15</strong>
<span class="details"></span>
```

Script:

```
var day = $('.day').text();
var month = $('.month').text();
var year = $('.year').text();
var fullDate = new Date('20'+year+'-'+month+'-'+day);

var now = new Date();
if (fullDate < now) {
    $('.event').addClass('past');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> If date greater than now add class via jQuery

and in your code it says:

```
if (selectedDate < now) {
```

maybe you should write it like this way:

```
if (selectedDate > now) {
```

if that's what you want.